CSS styling element on the top of an image
image with 3 lines on itI want to have a colour element looking like a border however slightly overlapping the img from the bottom part - just like in the attached picture.
I have tried to play with css border but it didn’t work as intended.
Any help would be appreciated.
I have used Bootstrap5 as well.
enter image description here


*image frame left styling original*/
.imageFrameLeft {
  display: inline-block;
/*  position: relative;*/
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0; 
}

.imageFrameLeft::before, .imageFrameLeft::after {
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: violet;
  content: '';
}

.imageFrameLeft::before {
  top: 0rem;

  right: 35rem;

  bottom: 6rem;

  left: 0;
  border-width: 6.5rem 0 6.5rem 0;

}

.imageFrameLeft::after {
  top: 0;
  right: 6.5rem;

  bottom: 6.5rem;
  left: 0rem;
  border-width: 0 0rem 0 6.5rem;

}


.imageFrameRight {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0; 
}

.imageFrameRight::before, .imageFrameRight::after {
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: navy;
  content: '';
}

.imageFrameRight::before {
  top: 0rem;

  right: 0rem;
  bottom: 6.5rem;

  left: 35rem;
  border-width: 6.5rem 0 6.5rem 0;

}

.imageFrameRight::after {
  top: 0;
  right: 0rem;
  bottom: 6.5rem;
  left: 5rem;
  border-width: 0 6.5rem 0 0rem;
}
<div class="imageFrameLeft">
    <img class="img-fluid mr-5" src="https://www.timeoutdubai.com/cloud/timeoutdubai/2021/09/11/hfpqyV7B-IMG-Dubai-UAE-1200x800.jpg" alt="">
</div>



<div class="imageFrameRight">
  <img class="img-fluid mr-5" src="https://www.timeoutdubai.com/cloud/timeoutdubai/2021/09/11/hfpqyV7B-IMG-Dubai-UAE-1200x800.jpg" alt="">
</div>




Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

But FYI, you can't do that with a border. A pseudo-element would be optimal here.

It's unclear what you are trying to do. Also, show your CSS code.

From what I see you want to use a red rectangle behind the image. Then put another rectangle in the same color in front of the image. Attached to the rectangle in the back.

I have tried before and after and it works once the image is in one place and with defined size. It doesn't work in general for any image or if the image is in a different place *different div.

I was thinking about adding border on the side, then border on the top but 50% width and then second border half width at the bottom and moved using padding and overlapping?

Here is a simple solution with one pseudoelement and a clip-path. The text is also in the pseudoelement.


.imageFrameRight {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 6.5rem 6.5rem 0 0;
}

.imageFrameRight::after {
  background-color: magenta;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% calc(100% - 6.5rem), calc(100% - 6.5rem) calc(100% - 6.5rem), calc(100% - 6.5rem) 6.5rem, 0% 6.5rem);
  display: block;
  height: 2rem;
  left: auto;
  padding: 50% 6.5rem 2rem 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: background-color .3s ease 0s;
  transition-property: background-color, color;
  content: 'Learn more \2192';
  width: 60%;
}

.imageFrameRight:hover::after {
  background-color: navy;
  color: white;
}
<figure class="imageFrameRight">
  <img class="img-fluid mr-5" src="https://www.timeoutdubai.com/cloud/timeoutdubai/2021/09/11/hfpqyV7B-IMG-Dubai-UAE-1200x800.jpg" alt="">
</figure>



